How to write latest JSF (pom.xml)? (NoClassDefFoundError:ApplicationFactory)
I use JSF project generator ( https://start.jakarta.ee/ )(choose: Jakarta EE 10) and try to write some JSF page.
But met many problem, and last:
/jakartaee-hello-world/pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakartaee-hello-world</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>jakartaee-hello-world</name>
    <description>
        This is a very simple Jakarta EE application generated by the official Eclipse Starter.
    </description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.report.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.report.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <jakartaee-api.version>10.0.0</jakartaee-api.version>
            <jakarta-jstl.version>3.0.0</jakarta-jstl.version>
            <glassfish-web.version>3.0.1</glassfish-web.version>
        <primefaces.version>14.0.0</primefaces.version>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</compiler-plugin.version>
        <war-plugin.version>3.4.0</war-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakartaee-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.faces-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakarta-jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${glassfish-web.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>${primefaces.version}</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>jakartaee-hello-world</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${war-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Server: "Tomcat v10.1.28 Server at localhost"
(Use Eclipse to develop)
Some solution from searched result is old.
I met the problem: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/application/ApplicationFactory".
Error/Exception:
...
9月 11, 2024 3:02:47 下午 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: 正在初始化環境「/jakartaee-hello-world」的 Mojarra 4.0.0
9月 11, 2024 3:02:47 下午 com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048：存在 PostConstruct/PreDestroy 附註。標示這些附註的 ManagedBeans 方法將表示附註已處理。
9月 11, 2024 3:02:47 下午 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/application/ApplicationFactory
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1023)
...


    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1144)
... 52 more
9月 11, 2024 3:02:47 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/application/ApplicationFactory
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:247)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3997)
...


    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/application/ApplicationFactory
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1023)
...


    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:263)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:179)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1144)
... 52 more
9月 11, 2024 3:02:47 下午 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: 正在初始化環境「/jakartaee-hello-world」的 Mojarra 4.0.0
9月 11, 2024 3:02:47 下午 com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048：存在 PostConstruct/PreDestroy 附註。標示這些附註的 ManagedBeans 方法將表示附註已處理。
jakarta.faces.FacesException: com.sun.faces.application.InjectionApplicationFactory
at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:434)
at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:323)
...


    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.sun.faces.application.InjectionApplicationFactory
at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:749)
at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:431)
... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.faces.application.InjectionApplicationFactory.<init>()
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3784)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:736)
... 42 more
9月 11, 2024 3:02:47 下午 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
SEVERE: Critical error during deployment:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/application/ApplicationFactory
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1023)
...


    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1144)
... 63 more
9月 11, 2024 3:02:47 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/application/ApplicationFactory
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:247)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3995)
...


    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/application/ApplicationFactory
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1023)


    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:263)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:179)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1144)
... 63 more
9月 11, 2024 3:02:47 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
9月 11, 2024 3:02:47 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/jakartaee-hello-world] startup failed due to previous errors
9月 11, 2024 3:02:47 下午 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextDestroyed
SEVERE: Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
jakarta.faces.FacesException: com.sun.faces.application.InjectionApplicationFactory
at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:434)
at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:323)
...


    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.sun.faces.application.InjectionApplicationFactory
at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:749)
at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:431)
... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.faces.application.InjectionApplicationFactory.<init>()
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3784)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:736)
... 36 more
9月 11, 2024 3:02:47 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
9月 11, 2024 3:02:47 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [1892] milliseconds

For more detail: https://docs.google.com/document/d/18KcVMkxCxzy1B1fLcaPv4g9lzpht5l2frK4IvpuA53Q/pub

Tomcat is not a Jakarta EE server. That's why it was absent on the starter site you found. Use a real Jakarta EE server such as WildFly/GlassFish/TomEE/etc (they're all listed as runtimes on the starter site you found!) or else adjust pom.xml specifically for Tomcat. See abovelinked duplicate for guidelines.

(1) pom.xml remove javax.servlet-api, (2) pom.xml remove <dependency>     <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>     <artifactId>weld-servlet-core</artifactId>     <version>3.1.5.Final</version> </dependency>, the weld-servlet-core-3.1.5.Final.jar , org/jboss/weld/environment/servlet/jsf/WeldApplicationFactory.class , the source code use import javax.faces.application.Application; import javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory; it appear in your error messsage. It is the error message source.

I use TomEE and solved all problems. Thank you very much.
